# Solve a Circular Dependency

Tags: objective-c, enums, circular-dependency

I my simple iOS objective-c app I have two .h file linked each other. One is a `Delegate Protocol`, the other one is an `Interface` for a class that defines an `NS_ENUM`.

This is the interface file (HistogramView.h):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "DiagramViewDataSource.h"
#import "DiagramViewDelegate.h"

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MoveOperation) {
    MOVE_BACKWARD,
    MOVE_FORWARD
};

@interface HistogramView : UIView

@property (weak) id <DiagramViewDelegate> delegate;
@property (weak) id <DiagramViewDataSource> dataSource;

@end
```

And this is the delegate protocol (DiagramViewDelegate.h):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "HistogramView.h"

@protocol DiagramViewDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)diagramSectionChangedWithOperation:(MoveOperation)op;

@end
```

In the delegate, compiler shows me an error linked to `MoveOperation` parameter: **"Expected a type"**. I tried also to add `@class HistogramView` before `@protocol` this way:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "HistogramView.h"

@class HistogramView;

@protocol DiagramViewDelegate <NSObject>

-(void)diagramSectionChangedWithOperation:(MoveOperation)op;

@end
```

but nothing changes. Can you help me? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Three options:

1. Remove the `#import "DiagramViewDelegate.h"` in `HistogramView.h` and before the `@interface` forward declare the protocol using `@protocol  DiagramViewDelegate`. Forward declarations are provided to address circularities, they are commonly used when two classes are mutually dependent (as in `@class classname;`)
2. Move the `#import "DiagramViewDelegate.h"` in `HistogramView.h` to *after* the `typedef`. This probably seems a bit "hacky", but is a direct observation that the `enum` is needed by `DiagramViewDelegate.h` and leads to...
3. Move the enum into its own header and include in both `DiagramViewDelegate.h` and `HistogramView.h`. This is the "cleaner" way to do (2) - i.e arrange the order items will be read by the compiler.

HTH

Comment: Option 4: Move the `enum` declaration to DiagramViewDelegate.h. But option 3 is best.

Comment: @rmaddy - mea culpa, I missed that one - but then I didn't say the list was exhaustive ;-)

Comment: This is a great explanation. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I typically add a Constants.h file to all of my projects.  In your particular case this is where you would add your `ES_ENUM`.

Then in each of the other files that use `ES_ENUM` add the `#import "Constants.h"`.